# Python 3.7 API hosting as Azure App Service for Windows

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We have our Python API working with 3.6 however as of today Azure support Python3.7. We have our product on Windows Platform and the python3.6 works well in our On-Prem environment. We are hosting our product as Azure SaaS and need to use host Python API through Azure App Service. We have done code changes for Python3.7 API and hosted on Azure App service for windows platform but dont get any output. We have referred the below Azure documentation and attached is the error screenshot.
Anyone who has face similar issue and resolved it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publish-to-app-service-windows?view=vs-2022
enter image description here

Comment: There's no screenshot attached

Comment: @Markus Meyer I have newly signed and its doesn't allow me to add any screenshot. I was trying to find out if some has hosted the Python3.7 API on the Azure Functions. The Azure functions has the option of only Linux platform however the API are build on windows based platform. We are getting certain error and not able to figure out if there has to be any change in the Code while hosting on Azure Function @ Linux.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I want to create a web app with a Windows + Python stack and it is not possible.  Azure only supports Python with Linux, which sucks if you're trying to use SQL Server.  Oh well, I guess I can just use docker and create my own stack.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the same by creating a sample `BottleWebProject`  by using the python version `3.7.9` and  deployed the web app to Azure App Service windows from Visual Studio successfully.

After creating the project in VS we have to add the virtual environment by right click on the `Python environments`      -->`Add Environment` as shown in the below Images:

[image]

[image]

Then we can run in our local environment and test through VS(Run without debugging mode) and you will see the output if app runs successfully like in the below image.

***Output***:

[image]

Then you have to publish the webapp to the Azure by creating the App service, App service plan and click on **publish** in VS as shown in below image:

[image]

**Output after publishing to Azure App Service Windows**:
[image]

[image]